Log rows affected for every model execution
I'm unable to log the rows affected, after every model run. I'm doing this to know how many rows got affected after every model run for observability purposes. I used call statement but it looks like it can be used again DMLs only and not for retrievals.
This is the pub_table model I have, for which, I would like to log the rows affected after the model run. I have 3 such models(including this), so is there a better approach for this, like defining it in the dbt_project.yml so that referencing it in the models, runs and logs the rows affected at the end of the each model run (kind of like post_hook) or are there any other approaches. I'm using dbt-core.
{% set airflow_info = fromjson(var('airflow_info', '{}')) %}
{% set max_meta_inserted_at = get_max_meta_inserted_at(ref("int_table"), airflow_info) %}

{{
    config(
        materialized="incremental",
        on_schema_change="fail",
        persist_docs={"relation": true, "columns": true},
        cluster_by=["_meta_source_file","_meta_use_case","transaction_date"],
        pre_hook=delete_existing_records(
            this, # pub_table
            ref("int_table"),
            max_meta_inserted_at
        )
    )
}}


{%- call statement('pub_table__insert_rows', fetch_result=True) -%}

    select *
    from {{ ref("int_table") }} as int_model
    {% if is_incremental() %}
        where int_model._meta_inserted_at = {{ max_meta_inserted_at }}
        # where 1<>1
    {% else %}  
        where int_model._meta_inserted_at is not null
    {% endif %}

{% endcall %}

{%- set result = load_result('pub_table__insert_rows') -%}
{{ log(result['response'].rows_affected ~ ' rows affected', info=True) }}

